# Xcode11 - controls like UIButton height is 48, in AppDelegate only in XR/XSMAX device

Tags: objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate, uicontrol, ios13

In iOS13 alone, for the iPhone XR/XS/XSMax or in the simulator, in the delegate method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I created an arbitrary UI controls, such as a `UIButton`, `UILabel`.

With or without frames assigned, their height is 48. Amazing question.

My Xcode is Xcode11, beta5

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UILabel *lab = [UILabel new];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton new];
    NSLog(@"btn.height = %f", btn.frame.size.height); // At this point the print is already 48
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100); // The print is still 48
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 300, 0)];
    self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 100);
    FMTestViewController *vc = [FMTestViewController new];
    vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 600);
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 100);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:btn];
    NSLog(@"self.window=%@", self.window);
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Did you try printing the button's height *after* you set the button's frame?

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, your approach is wrong.

Let me explain you a bit about the view hierarchy.

> UIWindow
>
> ---> UIViewController
>
> -------> UIView
>
> ------------> UIControls (UIButton, UILabel, UITextField etc.)

The iOS application view hierarchy follows the above pattern.

1. **Window (UIWindow):** Consider it as a canvas of drawing. Everything displays on the application is reside in this canvas. This is the top most parent of all child views and controls.

So you can not add UIControls directly to the UIWindow. You need something that can hold and arrange this controls.

2. **UIViewController:** So the UIViewController comes in picture. This is the container of all the controls (UIViews). It is responsible to manage all the UIControls. This is your point of interest. You can add all the controls in this class. Either by programming or using Storyboard. I would prefer to go with Storyboard.

One more thing I notice is that you are assigning  `FMTestViewController` frame using code, this is wrong there is no need to assign frame to the view controller. The frame is already adjust for all the devices by itself. And you should create view controller in Storyboard.

The best way to start it from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DesigningwithStoryboards.html).

Comment: Yes, but I wrote that code just to clarify my problem -- height = 48, which I know, of course, should be:
```   
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    FMTestViewController *vc = [FMTestViewController new];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

Comment: Well, this is beta version. It might possible that there are some fixes. But If you know the things that how views are created, why don't you try to create controls in ViewController.

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOption {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    FMTestViewController *vc = [FMTestViewController new];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    NSLog(@"self.window=%@", self.window);
    return YES;
} // It prints window === <UIWindow: 0x7fdbc5508c10; frame = (0 0; 414 48); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000113>

Comment: Are you using Storyboard? Are you using Xib or Storyboard for FMTestViewController? The issue is related with `FMTestViewController ` its height is 48.

Comment: Not used. A simple controller without adding any code.

Comment: In the stable Xcode version it is not the case, please file a bug on Apple forum.